# Invalid hook call error with React, semantic-ui and apollo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, semantic-ui, apollo-client

I created a delete button, which deletes user posts, with React, semantic-ui, and apollo-client.
The code looks like below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { Button, Icon, Confirm } from 'semantic-ui-react';

function DeleteButton({ postId }){
  const [confirmOpen, setConfirmOpen] = useState(false);

  const [deletePost] = useMutation(DELETE_POST_MUTATION, {
    variables: { postId }
  });

  return(
    <>
      <Button
        as="div"
        onClick={() => setConfirmOpen(true)}
      >
        <Icon name="trash"/>
      </Button>
      <Confirm
        open={confirmOpen}
        onCancel={() => setConfirmOpen(false)}
        onConfirm={deletePost}
      />
    </>
  );
};

const DELETE_POST_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation deletePost($postId: ID!){
    deletePost(postId: $postId)
  }
`;

export default DeleteButton;
```

I have the following error when I click the button:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
```

Where should I fix?
I think this code does not break the React Hook Rule.

---

The following information may be useful to debug.

**Directory Structure**

```
my-app
├── client
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
│        ├── App.js
│        ├── index.js
│        └── components
│            └── DeleteButton.js
├── node_modules
├── package.json
└── graphql
```

**react installation**

```
% npm ls react
my-app@1.0.0 /Path/to/my-app
├─┬ react-router-dom@5.2.0
│ ├─┬ react-router@5.2.0
│ │ ├─┬ mini-create-react-context@0.4.1
│ │ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
│ └── react@17.0.2
└─┬ semantic-ui-react@2.0.3
  ├─┬ @fluentui/react-component-event-listener@0.51.7
  │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
  ├─┬ @fluentui/react-component-ref@0.51.7
  │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
  ├─┬ @semantic-ui-react/event-stack@3.1.2
  │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
  ├─┬ react-dom@17.0.2
  │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
  ├─┬ react-popper@2.2.5
  │ └── react@17.0.2 deduped
  └── react@17.0.2 deduped

% npm ls react-dom
my-app@1.0.0 /Path/to/my-app
└─┬ semantic-ui-react@2.0.3
  ├─┬ @fluentui/react-component-event-listener@0.51.7
  │ └── react-dom@17.0.2 deduped
  ├─┬ @fluentui/react-component-ref@0.51.7
  │ └── react-dom@17.0.2 deduped
  ├─┬ @semantic-ui-react/event-stack@3.1.2
  │ └── react-dom@17.0.2 deduped
  └── react-dom@17.0.2
```

**Dependencies**

```
// /my-app/client/package.json
"dependencies": {
  "@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
  "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
  "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
  "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.20",
  "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
  "graphql": "^15.5.0",
  "graphql-tag": "^2.12.3",
  "react": "^17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
  "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
  "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
}

// /my-app/package.json
"dependencies": {
  "apollo-server": "^2.21.1",
  "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
  "graphql": "^15.5.0",
  "mongoose": "^5.12.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
  "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
  "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.3"
}
```

Comment: Can you try shifting the `DELETE_POST_MUTATION` inside of the functional component?

Comment: Shifting the query inside of `DeleteButton` does not solve the problem.

Comment: and if you change `const [deletePost] = useMutation(DELETE_POST_MUTATION, {
    variables: { postId }  }); ` by  `const [deletePost,{data}]` like in apollo [example](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#example-4)?

Comment: @antoineso Things does not change by adding `{data}`.

Comment: Ok, may be the issue could come from Confirm component can you just try to call delete somewhere else? I found this [issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/3943) on semantic github repo that can be a clue

Comment: @antoineso I tried to replicate the situation with codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-confirm-v3tu4), where I removed a mutation functionality. This code works well, so I think there is something wrong with my environment. But unlike the issue you found, I didn't run `npm link`.

Answer (score 3):

Solve this error by myself.

The problem is that **semantic-ui-react is not installed in client directory level.** You can see my faults in above **Dependencies**. The error message is `Invalid hook call`, but this is not related with React Hook.

I resolved this problem by the following procedure.

1. Install semantic-ui-react at `client` level

`client % npm install semantic-ui-react semantic-ui-css`

2. Uninstall semantic-ui-react at `sns-merng` level

`sns-merng % npm uninstall semantic-ui-react semantic-ui-css --save`

It is very important to run `npm` command at correct directory...

Comment: Greatly appreciate you posting a follow up here. Helped me solved the same problem after an hour of fustration. Thank you !

Comment: I also found this extremely helpful, many thanks!